# Phone Number regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I've just started using the re module for python and was making a regex that can take out all the phone numbers from a large text file.
Here is an example:
Number:02453952568, 0245-3952568, (0245)3952568, 0245 3952568, 3952568. I want something that can detect all of these.
Here is my code so far:

```
phoneregex=re.compile(r'((\(\d{4}\))|(d{4}))?(\s)?(-)?(\d{7})')
tpn=phoneregex.findall('(0245)3952568')
print (mzz)
```

But i get a wierd output:

```
[('(0245)', '(0245)', '', '', '-', '3952568')]
```

Is there any way i can make this more efficient,get a better result or change the regex entirely?

PS: Sorry if this isnt clear enough. I could not think of any other way of writing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python phonenumber regex doesn't work good enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711664/python-phonenumber-regex-doesnt-work-good-enough)

Comment: So do you want it to take all the phone numbers and just convert them all to normal phone numbers?

Comment: @dangee1705 no i just want it to return as it was in the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main issues with your regex: 
- You have parentheses around every small part that's why you get '' empty strings and '-' in the output. You should put parenthesis only around parts that you want to be returned (dashes and spaces are not that). If you remove these you'll get something more sensible:

```
phoneregex=re.compile(r'((\(\d{4}\))|(d{4}))?\s?-?(\d{7})')
phoneregex.findall('(0245)3952568')
> [('(0245)', '(0245)', '', '3952568')]
```

- Second issue is that you have '|' or in the regex that actually allows both is to match the string. Here you have first match of left-hand re '(0245)' and then right hand side matches both code and 7-digit number so you get code twice.

This simplified version will work for you:

```
phoneregex=re.compile(r'\(?(\d{4})[\s\)\-]?(\d{7})')
phoneregex.findall('(0245)3952568  0245-1231241414  0245-1234567')
[('0245', '3952568'), ('0245', '1231241'), ('0245', '1234567')]
```

Hope this helps.

Try to read a little more about how regexps work, because some behavior can be non-intuitive for novice: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions#greedy-vs-non-greedy-optional

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. This works perfectly, But can you tell me what that first '?' does?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to change your regular expression to `^...$` where `...` is your current regular expression. This way the phone numbers won't overlap.